# System::String to ASCII CODE

Tags: c++, .net, string, ascii

I'm having issues figuring out how to convert a System::String into its ascii code values. That is, take each character in the string, and create a new string containing each characters integer ascii value.

I know I can marshal a System::String into a std::string, and then do it that way (though I don't know how to do that either, exactly. I'm not up to date on my C++ string operations. My teacher makes us use character arrays...). But there has to be a purely .NET way of achieving this.

I'm very, very new to .NET. This is a homework assignment.

Any help you can give on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Sorry if this is a stupid question =/

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've actually had to do this for homework as well. What I did was using c++ in a .net environment, have a string. This string's characters can be accessed like those of an array, stringname[i...n]. Use a loop of your choice to iterate through all of the positions. To convert each position, all you need to do is:

```
int asciicode = stringname[i];
stringname[i] = asciicode;
```

Of course when you then cout the stringname, you will have a bunch of numbers all bunched together so you may not like that, but that's cosmetic things.

Comment: This could work, but its visual c++. I have to take input from a text box and convert it to its ascii value for another text box. data is stored in a text box as a System::String.

Comment: Oh okay, I haven't worked much with visual c++ as I find it to be a pain. But, the overall concept should be the same. Just use a string variable to work with that way your text in the text boxes aren't getting changed.

Comment: I suppose thats what I'll end  up using. marshalling to std::string it is.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream convert;

std::string stdString = "whatever the string is";
std::string buffer;
in charBuff;

for(int i = 0; i < stdString.length(); i++)
{
    charBuff = (int)stdString.at(i);
    convert << charBuff;
}

buffer = convert.str();
```